# having issue with registering , login user

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

*** i am learning web development , was following a tutorial by lama dev ,  when i made my backend seprately it was working fine but when i made request from client side nothing is working , dont know whts wrong , i even copied the source code of youtuber lama dev but it still not working please help ***

*** my auth route ***

```
const router = require("express").Router()
const User = require("../Models/User")
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt")

// REGISTER 

router.post("/register" , async (req , res) => {
    try {

        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        const hashedPass = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password , salt)
        
        const newUser = new User({
            username : req.body.username,
            email : req.body.email,
            password : hashedPass
        })
        const user = await newUser.save();
        res.status(200).json(user);
        console.log(user)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json(error);
        console.log(error)
    }
} );

//LOGIN

router.post("/login" , async (req, res ) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({username : req.body.username});
        !user && res.status(400).json("wrong credentials");

        const validate = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password , user.password);
        !validate && res.status(400).json('wrong credentials');

        const {password , ...others} = user._doc;
        res.status(200).json(others);
        console.log(others)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json(error);
        console.log(error)
    }
})


module.exports = router
```

*** my user schema ***

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username : {
        type : String ,
        required : true ,
        unique : true 
    },
    email : {
        type : String ,
        required : true,
        unique : true 
    },
    password : {
        type : String ,
        required : true
    },profilePic : {
        type : String,
        default : ""
    },
},
{ timestamps : true}
)

module.exports = mongoose.model("User" , UserSchema)
```

*** my index.js ***

```
const express = require("express");
const  app = express();
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");
const userRoute = require("./routes/users");
const postRoute = require("./routes/posts");
const categoryRoute = require("./routes/categories");
const multer = require("multer")
const path = require("path");




dotenv.config();
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/images")));

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL).then(console.log("connected to mongo")).catch((error)=> console.log(error))

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination : (req,file,cb) => {
        cb(null ,"images")
    }, 
    filename : (req,file,cb) => {
        cb(null , req.body.name);
    },
});

const upload = multer({storage:storage})

app.post("/api/upload" , upload.single("file") , (req ,res) => {
    res.status(200).json("file has been uploaded")
} )

app.use("/api/auth" , authRoute); 
app.use("/api/users" , userRoute);
app.use("/api/posts" , postRoute);
app.use("/api/categories" , categoryRoute);


 

app.listen("5000", ( ) => {
    console.log("Backend running")
});
```

*** my request  body using thunder client ***

```
{
  "username" : "harii",
  "email" : "harii@gmail.com",
  "passowrd" : "1234"
}
```

*** response ***

```
internal server error status 500
```

*** Error on my console ***

```
Error: data and salt arguments required
    at Object.hash (C:\Users\Krishna\Desktop\Blogs Web\Backend\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:137:17)
    at C:\Users\Krishna\Desktop\Blogs Web\Backend\node_modules\bcrypt\promises.js:29:12
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.module.exports.promise (C:\Users\Krishna\Desktop\Blogs Web\Backend\node_modules\bcrypt\promises.js:20:12)
    at Object.hash (C:\Users\Krishna\Desktop\Blogs Web\Backend\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:133:25)
    at C:\Users\Krishna\Desktop\Blogs Web\Backend\routes\auth.js:11:41
```

*** my backend was working fine in starting but when i made requests from client side  , all these errors started appearing  , don't know what is wrong , can u please help ***

*** i was following a youtube video by lama dev ***

Comment: Your password is probably undefined, `console.log(req.body.password)`  to confirm

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo here `"passowrd" : "1234"`.
It should be

```
{
  "username" : "harii",
  "email" : "harii@gmail.com",
  "password" : "1234"
}
```